# Upload created xml file to Google Drive at certain intervals

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I would like to upload specific xml file to my Google Drive account at certain intervals. My application creates xml file every 30 seconds. Xml file name is static. I develop my desktop application in .net platform and i am using C#. I examined [this url's instruction.](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) When i applied codes sample to my application, web based auth need to upload file.

My question is, can i upload xml file without web based auth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no user accounts that needs to be involved -- if you're not uploading to a user's account -- you can use "service accounts". There is a good introduction into service accounts on https://developers.google.com/events/8400075-3001/

If a user account is involved, it'd suggest you to ask permissions for offline access. So, you can retrieve new access tokens as current expires. Read more about offline access on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline All of our client libraries are supporting it. You can manually retrieve the an access and refresh token initially by exchanging with OAuth2 endpoints. Persist these tokens to inject them into the client library you're using. OAuth2 playground also explains the flow more in detail on https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: I have just one account. No more. I would like to upload file with using that account. My main language is turkish. So my english is not enough for understanding complicated instruction. Do you suggest any codes sample? I used smiliar API before. For example Facebook and Twitter API has offline access. Developer apply some values to their application once, they can post feed their account. So has Google Drive API similar approach?